# Combined pulling power of multiple engines in a train

Tags: summation

Apologies if this question doesn't belong here..

Its very common to see multiple engines being used when there are more coaches in a train. In a configuration with more than one engine a good amount of the first engine's pulling capacity is wasted because it has to pull the 2nd engine along (which I assume is much much heavier than a passenger coach).

When there are n engines is there a mathematical way to determine what the combined pulling power available for the passenger coaches (ie: after accounting for the wastage from 1st engine pulling 2-n and 2nd one pulling 3-n etc.)

Comment: The first engine is not pulling the second engine along; the second engine is quite capable of pulling itself along.

Comment: So in the arrangement with an engine at the front and an engine at the back, with the front engine having to pull the back engine and the back engine having to push the front engine, the train can't move at all! $\ddot{\smile}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an idealized model of physics, the answer is that the force that multiple engines apply to the passenger cars is the sum of the forces that they can individually apply.

The "idealized" part of the story comes from things like assuming that the trains are rigid bodies rather than being elastic (stretchable from one end to the other), and that the force applied by the engine to rotate the wheel is in fact constant, rather than varying over the period of the wheel's rotation (as is common in a steam engine, for instance). But for practical purposes, if engine 1 can pull 20 tons, and engine 2 can pull 30 tons, then engines 1 and 2 can pull 50 tons, plus or minus a few percent. And a pretty good argument is this:

place engine 1, followed by 20 tons of cars, then a gap, then engine 2, followed by 30 tons of cars. Clearly this assembly can leave the station just fine, as a pair of trains with a small gap between them.

Now, instead of a gap, place a small string connecting the front of engine 2 to the back of train 1. Now you have one long train (with a very weak link!) that can clearly proceed as well.

(This argument, in a somewhat different form, is due to Galileo!)

You might argue "But wait! In real trains, both engines are at the front!", and that's true... but if putting both at the front were less efficient, they'd never do it, because the cost of fuel is very substantial. :)

Comment: +1 but a minor correction suggested: "if engine 1 can pull 20 tons, and engine 2 can pull 3, then engines..." - Surely you meant to write "can pull 30, then..."

Comment: Fixed, thanks for careful proofreading!